# Low refresh rates work, high refresh rates don't

Tags: display, resolution, gpu, displayport, refresh-rate

I just purchased a new 144Hz monitor, but am having trouble setting it up with my PC (via displayport).

At first, I thought it was DOA as the screen would power on but not display anything. All that would happen is the screen would illuminate and go black on an infinite loop - sometimes it would just stay black though. I noticed that if I reduce the refresh rate back down to 60Hz, it would display the image fine. I also noticed that if I changed the displayport version to 1.1, the monitor would also work at the slightly higher refresh rate of 100Hz (but only with 6 bit color).

So there are a few things that I think could be wrong:

1. The monitor itself is faulty, and cannot handle high refresh rates
2. The cable is of a poor quality, and does not have sufficient bandwidth
3. The GPU is faulty

Does anyone have an effective strategy for diagnosing this issue and identifying the faulty component?

SPECS:

- **GPU**: AMD R9 390X
- **Monitor**: Samsung LC49HG90DMEXXY

  - 144Hz, 3840 x 1080, Freesync 2

WHAT I'VE TRIED

- Updated monitor firmware to latest version
- Updated GPU drivers
- Restarted computer and monitor
- Disabled/enabled freesync

Comment: I'd suspect your cable... they are fairly cheap, so that would be the first thing I'd try swapping... How long is your current cable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging I decided to purchase a higher quality display port cable and it worked fine after that. I selected my new cable from the [list of "certified" cables on the displayport website](https://www.displayport.org/product-category/cables-adaptors/) as I wanted to guarantee I'd get a good one.

Apparently all display port cables are *supposed* to have the same capabilities ([source](https://www.displayport.org/cables/how-to-choose-a-displayport-cable-and-not-get-a-bad-one/)), but quality does seem to make a difference especially when you're trying to push a high resolution picture at a high refresh rate.